# mismatched character ' ' expecting '\"'

Tags: javascript, fetch, yql

I am sending a request to a proxy and I get this error:

> {"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Query syntax error(s) [line 1:68 mismatched character ' ' expecting '\"']"}}

This is the URL:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url=%22https://1ex.trade/api/stats?market=BTC&currency=CHBT%22&format=json
```

Does anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

This is my request in JS

```
let fetchRequestForGettingTheNamesTroughProxy = function (exchangeUrl) {
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         const url = exchangeUrl;
         const yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="' + url + '"&format=json';
         let request = new Request(yql_url, {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: new Headers()
         });
         fetch(request)
             .then((resp) => resp.json())
             .then(function (data) {
                 console.log(data.query.results);
                 if (data.query.results === null){
                     fetchRequestForGettingTheNamesTroughProxy(exchangeUrl);
                 } else{
                     resolve(data.query.results.json);
                 }
             });
     });
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to properly encode the url parameter
The ampersand(&) in `exchangeUrl` breaks the `q` parameter hence breaks your query.

```
const yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + 
                'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="' + encodeURIComponent(url) + 
                '"&format=json';
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not properly encode your url it should look like

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url=%27https%3A%2F%2F1ex.trade%2Fapi%2Fstats%3Fmarket%3DBTC%26currency%3DCHBT%27&format=json
```

so use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
const yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '"&format=json';
```

Answer (score 1):

The & in your q URL needs to be encoded.

EG:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url=%22https://1ex.trade/api/stats?market=BTC%26currency=CHBT%22&format=json
```